# Can subqueries produce different execution plans than CTE's?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, cte

I was talking with the bossman, and he prefers subqueries over CTE's. Personally, I loathe subqueries. He mentioned that subqueries can be faster, but I am not convinced. I ran this short test:

```
    with classes as 
    (select top 10 Classkey from dimclass
    group by classkey
    order by count(1) desc),
    policies as (
    select CarrierKey, policykey, periodeffectivedate from dimpolicy),
    exposure as (
    select policykey, classkey  from DimExposure)


    select * from policies p
    inner join exposure x on p.PolicyKey = x.PolicyKey
    inner join classes c on x.ClassKey = c.Classkey
```

has an excution plan of:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJYJUZNHS

```
    select p.CarrierKey, p.PolicyKey, p.periodeffectivedate from dimpolicy p
    inner join (select policykey, classkey  from DimExposure) x on p.PolicyKey = x.PolicyKey
    inner join (select top 10 Classkey from dimclass
                group by classkey
                order by count(1) desc) c on x.ClassKey = c.Classkey
```

has the same execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJs_LbVSr

**Question:** Is this always the case? In the weird and wonderful world of SQL Server, the answer always seems to be *it depends*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170918/3270427

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is, I'd argue that the question isn't answerable. It's impossible to prove a negative and you won't find a guarantee in the product documentation. If you'd like an example of a technical difference between the two approaches, watch a few minutes of Paul White's [Query Optimizer Deep Dive](https://youtu.be/3I9mHjait2I?t=1609) session. It is not clear how someone could translate that into a performance best practice.

I suggest approaching the issue as a matter of coding style instead of trying to find a performance best practice. Switching out a CTE for a derived table or a derived table for a CTE is not a meaningful way to rewrite a query.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it depends. One case where a CTE is nicer than a derived table is when you need to reference it several times in the query. A silly example:

```
SELECT x,y
FROM (
    SELECT x,y FROM T WHERE p
) AS A
WHERE x = (SELECT MAX(x) FROM T WHERE p)
```

vs

```
WITH CTE (x,y) as ( 
    SELECT x,y FROM T WHERE p 
)
SELECT x,y FROM CTE WHERE x = (SELECT MAX(x) FROM CTE)
```

Different database engines treat multiple references to a CTE in different ways. In SQL Server, the CTE will generally be fully evaluated for each reference.